# Retrieve Laravel Model results based on multiple ID's

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, zend-search-lucene, relevance

I have implemented `ZendSearch` into my `Laravel` application.  I am using it as my search engine where users will type a search word, and then `ZendSearch` will return me an array of results ordered by relevance.  However, the array that `ZendSearch` returns, only returns my record ID's (it doesn't return any of the actual record information).

What would next be the correct way to query my Model to retrieve the results based on the `ZendSearch` array results which is just an array of ID's ordered based on relevance.

I know of `Model::find(1)` which would return my record with an ID of 1, but how can I feed that `find()` method an array of ID's that I want to be returned in the order I am giving it.

Comment: Care to comment why the downvote?

Comment: Another downvote? Why? :)  The laravel docs don't even say anything about findMany() or the ability to pass an array to the find function.  How is this not a legitimate question? :)

Comment: Up vote for you, this question did helps me. :)  I didn't see `findMany` in the document either, and it's in the [API document](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_findMany).

Comment: @PeterLiang broken link and I don't find on 8

Answer (score 341, accepted):

That's simple. Use `findMany`:

```
$models = Model::findMany([1, 2, 3]);
```

By the way, you can also pass an array to `find()` and it will internally call `findMany`:

```
$models = Model::find([1, 2, 3]);
```

---

Under the hood it just does a `whereIn` so you could do that too:

```
$models = Model::whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])->get();
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use `->find($ids)`

```php
$ids = [1,2,3,4]
$model = Model::find($ids);
```

in my case, i use `query` like this

```php
$ids = [1,2,3,4]
$model = Model::query()->find($ids);
```

I used that in Lumen.