# Laravel Eloquent query fetch all results where id equals array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to fetch all the data from my database where the id is equal to the id in an array. I want this to run in a sequential order for example if the array is called `$attributes` and looks like this;

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => 11
  1 => 12
]
```

I want to fetch all the results where the id is equal to `11` and group those together to loop through later. Then move on and query the DB for all the results where the id is equal to `12`.

I could create a loop and run a query over each iteration but if the array has 30+ id's that will result in 30 queries which are essentially the same just matching a different id.

Can I pass an array to a `where or` clause and chunk the results so I can loop thought it grouped later?

Comment: We need to see what you have tried / controller code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just pass the array like this:

```
 $models = Model::whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])->get();
```

[Retrieve Laravel Model results based on multiple ID's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28509985/retrieve-laravel-model-results-based-on-multiple-ids/28510008)

Comment: Can you pass an array variable as the second parameter?

Comment: Check out the link given about, it has some other ways of doing the same thing.

Comment: @archvist yes you can.